# PyroCMS - List all files in a theme folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Im building a custom module in **PyroCMS 2.2**

I cant see any documentation on how to create a dropdown box listing all files withing a theme directory.

This is to be used in my custom module /admin area. What I want to do is let the user select a file that exist in their theme directory.

The list must show all files listed in the partials/MOD_NAME directory.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate this.

```
theme_name\
          \js
          \css
          \views
               \partials\ 
                        \MOD_NAME\
```

Comment: There is a theme editor module at the store of Pyro, I don't have it, but I guess they must had same problem there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly related to Pyro but all you need to do is scan the directory and then output the files.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

```
$themeFiles = scandir(theme_root() . "/views/partials/MOD_NAME/");
```

*`theme_root()` is a made up function name to get the point across.*

For the actual path to the theme itself you might try looking at http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/api/classes/Plugin_Theme.html specifically this part:

> ## Path
>
> `path()` : string Get the path to the theme
>
> Usage: `{{ theme:path }}`
>
> ## Returns
>
> `string` The path to the theme (relative to web root).

Comment: Yes I was also thinking this too, just wondering if myro have some preexisting tools. Otherwise thankyou for reminding me about the scandir function